# Why is $ \frac{n}{2} \leq \frac{N^{m+1} - 1}{N - 1} $ equal to $ n \leq 2N^{2m} $

Tags: inequality

According to a reliable source, $ \frac{n}{2} \leq \frac{N^{m+1} - 1}{N - 1}$ simplifies to $n \leq 2N^{2m} $. I'm having difficulties proving this assumption.
It makes sense to me that we should be able to somehow discard $N - 1$ on both sides of the right side fraction. So the first steps would be

$ \frac{N^{m+1} - 1}{N - 1}$

$ \frac{(N - 1) \times N^{m}}{N - 1}$

$  N^{m}$

So the inequation is now equal to

$ \frac{n}{2} \leq N^{m} $

Now we can multiply both sides by 2, and we get

$ n \leq 2N^{2m} $

Which is the desired inequation. The only problem is the very first step, which is getting rid of $N - 1$ at the start. I noticed that if I were to reverse $ \frac{(N - 1) \times N^{m}}{N - 1}$, I would get $ \frac{N^{m+1} - N^{m}}{N - 1}$ instead of $ \frac{N^{m+1} - 1}{N - 1}$. Could anyone tell me at which point I made a mistake?

Comment: What kind of numbers are $n,N,m$? Real? Rational? In $[0,1]$?

Comment: $\frac{n}{2} \leq N^{m} \not\Rightarrow n \leq 2N^{2m}$!!! (I meant that they are not necessarily equivalent statements)

Comment: Also $\frac{N^{m+1}-1}{N-1} = 1 + N + N^2 + ... + N^m$ and for $N>0$, $\sum_{k=0}^m N^k > N^m$.

Comment: @Eevee Trainer All three numbers should be natural numbers.

Comment: @Prometheus
I see my mistake now, $ \frac{n}{2} \leq N^{m} $ is equal to simply $ n \leq 2 \times (N^{m})$.

Comment: Also I found a counterexample to the original statement: n=1, N=0, m=1. @Patyo21 Is there any sort of domain restrictions?

Comment: @Prometheus As far as I understand it, no. $N = q \cdot S(n)\cdot d^{S(n)}$ where $q$, $S(n)$ and $d^{S(n)}$ should all be natural numbers. $\frac{N^{m+1} - 1}{N - 1}$ comes from $\sum^{m}_{i=0} N^{i} = \frac{N^{m+1} - 1}{N - 1}$.

Comment: Well, there ARE restrictions then, in the form $N, n, m \in \mathbb{N}$